# Rowan tree unknown disease

Tags: diseases, fruit-trees

So 2 years ago I have got myself a Sorbus Likjornaja a type of Rowan tree, very very very hard to come by in my area. For those 2 years, it grew splendid with absolutely no worry or issues. But this year for the last week more exactly it started to dry out and I'm afraid not to lose it. As I am not sure what is happening here if its a disease or anything else I need a bit of help from anyone who knows about Rowan Trees

Here are some pictures:
[image: rowan]

[image: rowan tree with wilted leaves]

As you can see  it started to dry out

Comment: what part of the world are you  in? Is the tree planted in the ground or in a pot?

Comment: Europe Romania, in ground